# Why will Oracle Driver be loaded when initializing driver for sybase in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sybase

I have a really strange issue.
I have two projects built with maven. 
One project is DAO layer, the other is service layer. 
The service layer projects depends on the DAO layer project, so the DAO layer projects is referenced in pom of service layer project.
The DAO layer depends on oracle driver and sysbase driver. 
Bot databases (oracle + sybase) work as expected when I run any testclasses from the DAO project. 
But when I run any testclasses from the service layer project, I always get the stacktrace below.
I get this stacktrace, even I don't even access the oracle database.

I already added the oracle driver as a dependency to the service layer pom, but it didnt help.
It looks as somehow the sybase driver causes allDrivers to be loaded (DriverManager.getDrivers()) but the oracle driver lateron can't be found.

BUT: When I remove the oracle dependency from the DAO project (without any code changes at all), I can run test from service layer projects without problems.

Anyone any idea how to solve this ?

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:415)    at
>   java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:555)
>     at
>   java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:547)
>     at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:449)
>     at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:426)
>     at
>   com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.registerWithDriverManager(SybDriver.java:711)
>     at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.(SybDriver.java:140)   at
>   com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver.(SybDriver.java:104)  at
>   de.miditec.carpark.dao.BasicDAO.createPersistenceUnit(BasicDAO.java:238)

Comment: It looks that somewhere in your tests setup you list "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" but don't have it on your CLASSPATH of the actual tests. It somehow gets into the list returned by [`.getDrivers`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getDrivers--) but the test class loader does not have the access. Look through your configs / build scripts for mentions of the Oracle driver.

Comment: `DriverManager` will automatically load drivers on the classpath. This specific problem seems to be a combination of Sybase loading/registering itself incorrectly, and possibly a problem with your Oracle driver. Make sure you use the latest version of both.